# Representing your own case

Tags: indian-penal-code, india

Are there any prerequisites to represent one's own case before a jury? Specific answer targeting Indian Law would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt there's any restriction, but it's not a good idea even for a lawyer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legally, the answer will differ by jurisdiction. Practically, the answer is summed up in the old proverb: "The man who is his own lawyer has a fool for a client."

Even experienced lawyers rarely represent themselves, especially when outside their area of professional expertise.  There are two reasons people hire lawyers: technical expertise, and objective advice. You need both.

I have never represented myself, but I have acted for clients against self-represented (in the U.S., "pro se") litigants. I have never seen one who ever had a hope of succeeding. Usually all of the lawyers involved, and the judge, knew their case was doomed from the first hapless pleading. Usually, the pro se litigant was convinced that he was sure to prevail.

Comment: The OP asked about indian law this answer seems to address US Law.

Comment: @chapka, I've read multiple cases whereby people representing themselves actually won. Do you mind elaborating on these cases?